# Set the value of input text field from code behind C# Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I'm trying to set html input field text value from the C# behind code. the way those inputs create is through a java script loop. So I didn't have much luck adding the run at server, or assign the value through <%= %>

Here is my script

```
var mytable = "<table class=\"Inside\"  >";
var z = 0;
var value = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
mytable += "<tr>";

for (var C1 = 1; C1 <= 3; C1++) {
    mytable += "<td>";

    mytable += "<table class=\"inside\"  >";
    for (var C2 = 1; C2 <= 3; C2++) {
        mytable += "<tr>";

        for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
            z++;
            //value = z.toString();
            //if (value % 3 != 0)  value= ;

            mytable += "<td> <input id=" + i + "x" + j + " name=" + z + "  
type=\"text\"  maxlength=\"1\" oninput=\"this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-
9]/g,'');\"  value= " +z+ " runat=\"server\" /> </td>";


        }




        mytable += "</tr>";
    }


    mytable += "</tr></table>"; mytable += "</td>";}



mytable += "</tr>";
}


mytable += "</tr></table>";

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#myTable").append(mytable);


})
```

I'm trying to access the input from C# something like

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

1x2.value="1";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Id, in input you can use.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
    sb.Append(@"$('#YOUR_IDINPUT').val('"+SomeValue+"');");
    sb.Append(@"</script>");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Button1,this.GetType(), "JSCR", 
    sb.ToString(),false);
}
```

Sorry, if i can not help you.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. That's something that could definitely help. But, I', not able to get it working. few answers maybe help. what is this line   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Button1,this.GetType(), "JSCR", 
    sb.ToString(),false); and what is JSCR specifically. Can you append a value ?

Comment: This is the line for work with the script. He registering your script and added to your page. "JSCR" its simpled key of the script, you can called how you would. With this is the method you can use all javascript method, for open or hide modal, using some bootstrap progress bar, chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create HTML controls with JavaScript. If you wish to send some data to the server, you can get the desired values using JavaScript and assign it to an ASP control (e.g. HiddenField), then access its value on server-side.

```js
var mytable = "<table class=\"Inside\"  >";
var z = 0;
var value = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  mytable += "<tr>";
  for (var C1 = 1; C1 <= 3; C1++) {
    mytable += "<td>";
    mytable += "<table class=\"inside\"  >";
    for (var C2 = 1; C2 <= 3; C2++) {
      mytable += "<tr>";
      for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        z++;
        //value = z.toString();
        //if (value % 3 != 0)  value= ;

        mytable += "<td> <input id=" + i + "x" + j + " name=" + z + " type=\"text\"  maxlength=\"1\" oninput=\"this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');\"  value= " + z + " /> </td>";
      }
      mytable += "</tr>";
    }
    mytable += "</tr></table>";
    mytable += "</td>";
  }
  mytable += "</tr>";
}
mytable += "</tr></table>";

function CreateTable() {}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTable").append(mytable);
})

function getInputValue(element) {
  $("#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>").val($("#1x2").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myTable"></div>
```

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="getInputValue(this);" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="HiddenField Value:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

c# code-behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += "<br />Input 1x2: " + HiddenField1.Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi Attila, thanks for the feedback. I can actually get the input field values easily with Request.Form["1x2"] from code behind. Problem is how to set or change those inputs field value from the Code behind. I want to change the value of the input field it self not copy it and change it

Comment: @Adam Bahrani,  I am afraid you can only do that on client using JavaScript similar to my example. Of course there are plenty of other approaches, but again only on client side using JavaScript.