# Set value of input control created at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using C# to create controls at **runtime** on a form page.

Due to the styling requirements, the control is created as an **input** control, using a **Literal**, adding to a grid (the **tc** is the table cell in the example).

This is an example of creating the control:

```
    ltl = new Literal();
    ltl.Text =
        "<div class=\"number-input\"> " +
        "  <button onclick=\"this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown(); return false;\" class=\"nopopup minus\">-</button> " +
        "  <input runat=\"server\" ID=\"edProduct1Quantity\" class=\"nopopup quantity\" min=\"0\" name=\"edProduct1Quantity\" value=\"0\" step=\"12\" type=\"number\"> " +
        "  <button onclick=\"this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp(); return false;\" class=\"nopopup plus\">+</button> " +
        "</div> ";

    tc.Controls.Add(ltl);
```

When the form is processed, I can read the value using the name, for example:

```
    FieldText = Page.Request.Form["edProduct1Quantity"].ToString();
```

However, after the control is created on the form, I am then attempting in another routine to set a default value. I have tried a couple of related posts on Stack Overflow to set values, but nothing works.

For example:

```
    Page.Request.Form["edProduct1Quantity"] = "1";
```

will raise an exception.

It's not a page lifecycle issue, as I was originally doing this using a TextBox control instead of an input control and it was working ok. I just can't find a way to set the value now that it's an input control.

Is there any way to set the value?

Comment: You cannot add a string with `runat=server` and expect it to work, Webforms does not work that way.

Comment: @VDWWD correct, that would have been a hangover from an attempt to access it based on a similar method to when it's an actual TextBox control. It's the conversion to an <input> control that has created the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a version of the javascript answer from this question:

[Set the value of input text field from code behind C# Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947141/set-the-value-of-input-text-field-from-code-behind-c-sharp-asp-net)

In the page load, I added scripts for each control that needed initialising:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
sb.Append(@"$('#edProduct1Quantity').val('"+SomeValue+"');");
sb.Append(@"</script>");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "edProduct1QuantityStartup", sb.ToString(), false);
```

It took a couple of goes to get the script configured correctly for what I needed, but it does the job.